# React Native - How to simulate a RefreshControl in a horizontal scrollable list

Tags: react-native, horizontalscrollview, react-native-scrollview

## The Problem

I am developing a **horizontal scrollable list** which always scroll one entire screen (i.e. one "page") on each swipe. When it is on the first page and the user **pulls to right** again, I need to **refresh the entire list**.

As for a vertical `ScrollView`, a standard `RefreshControl` would appear if a user pulls down when the view is at its topmost position. But for the horizontal version, there is no standard solution.

## My Experiment

#### The idea

I have tried to add a `PanResponder` to capture the touching and moving events. Note that I am using a `VirtualizedList` in my application. The basic logic is that:

- I create a hidden `View` (whose width is set to 0 by default) with an `ActivityIndicator` in it, and insert this View as the `ListHeaderComponent` into the `VirtualizedList`
- I listen to the `VirtualizedList`'s `onScroll` event and keep saving the latest scroll position
- When then scroll position is nearly 0, and the user pulls right (event captured gesture through `PanResponder`), then I animate the width of the hidden View with ActivityIndicator to simulate the RefreshControl behavior

#### The result

However, the `PanResponder` does not properly capture the desired event. Most of the time, when I pull right at the beginning of the `VirtualizedList` (on an Android device), only the standard hitting edge animation appears (a gradient blue layer shows up).

By adding some logs, I found that `onPanResponderGrant` can occasionally be triggered, but none of `onPanResponderMove`, `onPanResponderRelease`, `onPanResponderTerminate` or `onPanResponderTerminationRequest` is ever fired.

When `onPanResponderGrant` is triggered, the hidden `ActivityIndicator` occasionally appears paritally. The "pull to right" effect only shows up shortly and always stops instantly with only a very narrow part of the hidden View appears.

I guess that the underlying `ScrollView` steals the event and prevents my code from responding. But even if I set `onPanResponderTerminationRequest` to always reture `false` still won't help. Even if I directly subsitute the `VirtualizedList` with a `ScrollView` also yield the same result.

Does anyone have any idea how to properly capture the touch and move event when ScrollView scrolls beyond is top? Or is there another viable way to implement a horizontal version of a `RefreshControl`?

## The Experimental Code

```js
import React from 'react'
import {
  Text, View, ActivityIndicator, ScrollView, VirtualizedList,
  Dimensions, PanResponder, Animated, Easing
} from 'react-native'


let DATA = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

class Test extends React.PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      refreshIndicatorWidth: new Animated.Value(0),
    };

    this.onScroll = evt => this._scrollPos = evt.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
    this.onPullToRefresh = dist => Animated.timing(this.state.refreshIndicatorWidth, {
      toValue: dist,
      duration: 0,
      easing: Easing.linear,
    }).start();
    this.resetRefreshStatus = () => {
      Animated.timing(this.state.refreshIndicatorWidth, {
        toValue: 0,
      }).start();
    };

    const shouldRespondPan = ({dx, dy}) => (this._scrollPos||0) < 50 && dx > 10 && Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy);
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
        return shouldRespondPan(gestureState)
      },
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => {
        return shouldRespondPan(gestureState)
      },
      onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
        console.warn('----pull-Grant: ' + JSON.stringify(gestureState));
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        console.warn('----pull-Move: ' + JSON.stringify(gestureState));
        this.onPullToRefresh(gestureState.dx)
      },
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => {
        console.warn('----pull-TerminationRequest: ' + JSON.stringify(gestureState));
        return false
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
        console.warn('----pull-Release: ' + JSON.stringify(gestureState));
        this.props.refreshMoodList();
      },
      onPanResponderTerminate: () => {
        console.warn('----pull-Terminate: ' + JSON.stringify(gestureState));
        this.resetRefreshStatus();
      },
    });

    this.renderRow = this.renderRow.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, prevContext) {
    console.warn('----updated: ' + JSON.stringify(this.props));
    this.resetRefreshStatus();
  }

  renderRow({item, index}) {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', width: Dimensions.get('window').width, height: '100%'}}>
        <Text>{item}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    /******* Test with a VirtualizedList *******/
    return (
      <VirtualizedList
        {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
        data={DATA}
        ListEmptyComponent={<View/>}
        getItem={getItem}
        getItemCount={getItemCount}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this.renderRow}
        horizontal={true}
        pagingEnabled={true}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        ListHeaderComponent={(
          <Animated.View style={{flex: 1, height: '100%', width: this.state.refreshIndicatorWidth, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large"/>
          </Animated.View>
        )}
        onScroll={this.onScroll}
      />
    );
    /******* Test with a ScrollView *******/
    return (
      <View style={{height:Dimensions.get('window').height}}>
        <ScrollView
          {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
          horizontal={true}
        >
          <View style={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 2, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
            <Text>123</Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const getItem = (data, index) => data[index];
const getItemCount = data => data.length;
const keyExtractor = (item, index) => 'R' + index;

export default Test;
```

## Temporary Workarounds (Not so perfect)

- **Fire the refresh event (as well as the animation) directly inside `onPanResponderGrant`**: This way, I'm still not able to track touch moves. So the scrolling pane cannot follow the touch point.
- **Move the operations in `onPanResponderMove` to `onMoveShouldSetPanResponder` with additional conditions** (e.g. adding my own "grant" condition judgment): This way, I can track the touch movements, but since I haven't got the real "grant", I'm not able to capture the `*Release`/`*Terminate`/`*End` event (i.e., I won't know when the touch event ends, therefore never actually know when to fire the refreshing event!)

## Perfect Solutions

Waiting for your idea...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `contentOffset` to determine if a user has "pulled to refresh" on a horizontal list. The following should work on both a `FlatList` and a `ScrollView`:

```
onScroll={(e) => {
  const xOffset = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;

  // logic goes here to handle a negative value

}}
scrollEventThrottle={16}
```

You can conditinally do something or set a flag when the xOffset hits a certain value. Hopefully that will get you started!

Comment: Also you can alter `scrollEventThrottle` to determine how frequently `onScroll` is fired, as to not lose animation frames

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This should work on iOS devices, but for Andriod, the `*List`/`ListView`/`ScrollView` simply stops scrolling after reaching its top, so negative scroll position never occurs. That's why I have been troubling to implement my own `PanResponder`.

Comment: Not working on android as @DeNG mentioned